# script inside Razor, unable to correct using @:

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0, razor, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

I get compile error at `$(this).id)`

```
<script>
            if ('@content.ToList().Count' > 0) 
            {
                $(".divContainer").text('@content.Where(p => p.ContainerID == `$(this).id`).Select(p => p.TextContents).First()');
            }
            else 
            {
                $(".divContainer").text("Please enter the text");

            }
</script>
```

How to add the id of 'this div' with class 'divcontainer' inside the razor code `@content.Where(p => p.ContainerID == "ID".Select(p => p.TextContents).First()`

**question made simpler.**

How to write the following code correctly

```
@string text = $(this).text();
```

Here razor variable 'text' is assigned with Jquery text value.

Comment: Do you have the backticks `\`$(this).id\`` like that in your code?

Comment: i wanted that particular code to be placed as a nonrazor code, so to emphasize that i used the quotes there..

Comment: If I understand correctly, I'm afraid what you are asking is not possible. You should keep in mind that razor produces HTML/JS (server-side) that is then rendered by the browser (client-side). The following code: `@string text = $(this).text();` is trying to assign a client-side value to a server-side variable.

Answer (score 0):

use .attr() method of jquery to get the id

```
 if ('@content.ToList().Count' > 0) 
    {
        $(".divContainer").text('@content.Where(p => p.ContainerID == $(this).attr("id")).Select(p => p.TextContents).First()');
    }
    else 
    {
        $(".divContainer").text("Please enter the text");

    }
```

Comment: sorry this doesnt solve my issue, i need to insert a script code within a razor code... and the script code is $(this).attr("id").. i need the correct syntax